# Get outliers in a DataFrame with date

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I have a DataFrame from a list of datetime objects. 
I'm looking to get the outlier dates in the set. I tried using the std() 
functions and google with no luck. :( Any help please?

```
date_list = []
for event in get_events():
    date_list.append(event["date"])

event_series = pandas.DataFrame(date_list)
# get outlier set here.
```

I'm looking for a dataset like

```
[ 1/1/2000,
1/2/2000,
1/3/2000,
1/4/2000,
1/1/2005 ]
```

to return 1/1/2005 as an outlier.

Comment: What conditions will  you use to identify / qualify a data point as an outlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where `df` is your dataframe:

```
print(df[ np.abs(df.Data - df.Data.mean()) > 1.5*df.Data.std() ])
```